# did they change astype('string') in python 3?

Tags: python, upgrade, python-3.5

I'm getting a weird error in some really basic code since (I think) upgrading to python 3.5 (from 2.7)

When trying to open a file (full of bit strings) and them manipulate the strings like this:

```
#bit string data
data = open(read_path+'genomes'+str(time)).read().replace(',','\n').replace('\n','')
x = data.split()
CA = np.array(x).astype('string')
Genomes = np.reshape(CA, (size,size))
genomelength = len(Genomes[0][0])
for entry in range(0, size**2): total_mut1[entry] = np.array(sum_digits(CA[entry])).astype('int')
mut_array1 = np.reshape(total_mut1, (size,size))
```

Which worked before the upgrade...

I now get this error:

```
CA = np.array(x).astype('string')
TypeError: data type "string" not understood
```

Is this just a silly fix (I hope). thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens with astype(str)?

Comment: that's fixed it, thanks @pvg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is information on options for dtype:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Specifically:

> Several python types are equivalent to a corresponding array scalar when used to generate a dtype object:
>
> int    int_
>
> bool   bool_
>
> float  float_
>
> complex    cfloat
>
> str    string
>
> unicode    unicode_
>
> buffer void
>
> (all others)   object_

As the comment above suggested, .astype(str) should work.

EDIT

Actually this information is taken from Python2.7, I also tried this and unicode did not work, but astype(str) defaults to unicode (as one would expect in python3). Interesting though, since these string codes seem to work:

> 'b'   boolean
>
> 'i'    (signed) integer
>
> 'u'    unsigned integer
>
> 'f'   floating-point
>
> 'c'    complex-floating point
>
> 'O'    (Python) objects
>
> 'S', 'a'  (byte-)string
>
> 'U'    Unicode
>
> 'V'    raw data (void)

Information about strings in python3 vs python2 (probably the most significant change) is here:

https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: `astype(unicode)` might work even better, because that's the type of non-decorated string literals in Python 3.

Comment: just tried this and it didn't work...      CA = np.array(x).astype(unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Comment: see edit, astype(str) and astype("U") result in the same array, while astype("S") treats the data as a byte string